# No Systems Sounds when .exe is placed in Program Files folder

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe3

I have a very odd issue.  My application plays a system sound as an alarm.  This has worked fine throughout my build (XE3, VCL Metropolis UI).  However now it's built and installed in the my Program Files (x86) folder I get no sound at all.  If I copy the exe from the program files folder to the desktop it works fine and the sound is heard again.  Any thoughts?

Here's the one line of code:

```
PlaySound(PWideChar('Notification.Looping.Alarm'), 0, SND_ALIAS or SND_ASYNC);
```

(I have MMSystem referenced in the uses clause)

Windows 8.1, XE3

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a test, try running as administrator and see if it works. If it does, then it's a permissions issue.

Comment: What is the PlaySound function result? (true/false)

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some debugging.  Otherwise, [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post a MCVE so we can attempt to reproduce the problem.